# Variance of a sum of i.i.d random variables

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

have the following stochastic process: $\{X_{t}\}_{t\in\mathbb{z}}$

$$X_t=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
G_{t} \text { if } t \text { is even } \\
U_{t} \text { if } t \text { is odd }
\end{array}\right.$$

Where $G_{t}$ is distributed normally with variance $1$, and $U_{t}$ is distributed uniformly with variance $1/3$. The $G_{i}$s and $U_is$ are, respectively, i.i.d.

I want to compute the variance of the sample average of this process for an even $T$. Is the following correct?

$$\bar{X}(T)=\frac{1}{T}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{T / 2} U_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{T / 2} G_{j}\right]\implies \begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}[\bar{X}(T)] &=\frac{1}{T^{2}}\left[\frac{T}{2} \frac{1}{3}+\frac{T}{2}\right] \\
&=\frac{2}{3T}
\end{aligned}$$

However, I am told by a solution manual that the variance is instead $\frac{1}{3T}$. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This does not depend on the shapes of the distributions. Take a simple example to check:  $U_1=\pm 1$ with equal probability and independently $G_2=\pm 1$ with equal probability.  I think you get $\text{Var}(\frac{U_1+G_2}{2}) = \frac13$ which is $\frac{2}{3T}$ when $T=2$